# Converting Code::Blocks projects to Visual Studio Code (Linux)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, project, codeblocks, converters

I have Code::Blocks workspace (with a single root) with few dozens of C++ projects. Code::Blocks stores projects relations in .workspace file and projects in .cbp files. Is it there any way to convert this to Visual Studio Code (VSC) projects, how?

There is cbp2make tool which makes .mak file from .cbp but I don't think it is suitable. I suppose some converter to CMake files would do the job, because there are VSC extensions for CMake, but I don't see such converters. Any ideas?

The platform is Linux.

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=24239.0) question in Code::Blocks forums, there is no way to transform CBP to Cmake. Depending on your filesystem organization, maybe you can create a script that iterates each CBP and use `cbp2make` on them, then create a new VSC workspace with all of them.

Comment: @GaryNLOL I have .mak files from cbp2make for every project in its folder, but how to create VSC workspace with them?
If you know how, please write it as answer.